# How do I abstract away from using RogueWave in legacy code?

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, wrapper, rogue-wave

I have been tasked with removing RogueWave components from a legacy C++ codebase.  To do so, I am attempting to build wrappers around the existing components, make sure that the code functions the same, and then choose a different library like boost to stick into the wrappers.

One of the problems I am coming against is that much of the codebase expects pointers to RogueWave objects.  I can create a dummy Wrapper Object class that points to the original RogueWave object, but I cannot figure out how to correctly wrap pieces of that RW object, such as iterator items when the code expects a modifiable pointer into the original object.

Any suggestions, or advice for alternate approaches?
(Note: I am a bit rusty on my C++)

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why are you removing the Rogue Wave stuff? And +1. This is a textbook scenario that screams for careful application of patterns. Also, i don't think you'll be able to get away from refactoring your client code. You'll need to produce a more generic interface and then update the client calls.

Comment: Which RogueWave components are you trying to get rid of?

Comment: @John Dibling The main rw component I am trying to remove is the serialization, which is tied heavily into the rw framework.

@Paul Sasik: I don't know the official reason, but it is what I have been assigned to do.  It would be useful to be able to switch back and forth between components anyhow as newer and better things come out, anyhow.

Comment: Exactly. I see this issue in legacy software often where 3rd party functionality is tightly embedded into the code without thought of being able to swap later. In my experience the need to swap actually has not been due to bigger and better but due to component providers going out of business. It is much easier to provide a generic, pluggable interface up front then to deal with a defunct company's API years down the road.

Comment: Could use share a non-trivial but not-too-long snippet of client code that uses RW objects? That might spur the discussion.

Comment: Here's a generic example (assuming someDlist is a RWDlistCollectable and MyCollectableClass inherits from RWCollectable):

    RWDlistCollectablesIterator iterator(someDlist);
    MyCollectableClass curr;
    while((curr = (MyCollectableClass *)iterator()) != rwnil){
       if(curr.meetsCriteria()){
          curr.modifySelf();
       }
    }

Comment: @Paul did you find any solutions? I am having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

[Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)

[Bridge Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern)

If those do not work out:

[Facade Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)

Comment: I understand how these work for single classes.  My problem is that I do not know/understand how to design/implement this for multiple classes.  For example, if I have a RW Collection class, and inside are RW Strings, how do I access the contents of the wrapper collection as wrapper strings?

Comment: Do you mean you have something like RWCollection<RWString>, and you need to replace it with MyCollection<MyString>?  I don't see the problem.  Care to elaborate?

Comment: If I define MyCollection as an adapter that contains an instance of RWCollection<RWString>, when I iterate through MyCollection I will get pointers to RWStrings rather than MyStrings.  How do I convert one to the other and return a pointer to the newly wrapping MyString?

Comment: I don't think that will work.  You cannot expose any RW.  So you need to wrap the RWStrings, and the RWCollection<>::iterators, and everything else.

Comment: Given all the comments and given how corporate directives can change like the wind; in my humble opinion, **strike while the iron is hot** (and you have the funding) and go for the Facade Pattern. I think it would fix it now, and any changes in the future, when that new manager decides it’s now going to be all boost or whatever the flavor of the month is. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar task about 10 years ago, it turned out most of the stuff we used Roguewave for was part of the standard in C++.  In most instances there was a direct C++ standard data structure that was able to replace the Roguewave usage.

If you can't do a direct replacement and might use yet another 3rd party library or your own library, the patterns that JustBoo mentioned would be ideal.