# Replace RogueWave with standard library by writing a wrapper

Tags: c++, stl, std

With reference to this post

[How do I abstract away from using RogueWave in legacy code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523456/how-do-i-abstract-away-from-using-roguewave-in-legacy-code)

The new wrapper will have equivalent RogueWave methods wrapped around standard library. Something like -

```
template<class T, class Container = std::deque<T> >
class my_stack
{
public:
    void push(const T& t)
    {
        m_stack.push(t);
    }
    // ... so on ...

protected:
    std::stack<T, Container> m_stack;
};
```

How do we expose the standard library methods which do not exist in RogueWave.

Does the wrapper be a union of RogueWave::stack and std::stack methods ? Or do we expose the underlying std::stack object for the client to directly call std::stack methods ? Does the client use std library directly or everything through a wrapper ?
Thoughts please.

Thanks.

Comment: You should consider just rewriting the legacy code.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you don't replace `RougeWave::stack` with `std::stack` without a wrapper?

The wrapper approach requires work to maintain the interface between your wrapper and the container class. You need to get things like rvalue references right, but unless you are adding significant functionality (and with `std::stack` that seems unlikely) the benefit you can get from this is limited.

I see that you have `protected:`, so it could be that you are using inheritance on your containers. That could also be a good thing to remove.

`std::stack` is part of the language now, it will have a longer life than a third party library like RogueWave.

Comment: Totally agree. First thing I have to do is remove RogueWave as soon I can. Changing the code will take time due to its size and platform's it supports. So at this time I am looking for a temporary wrapper but at the same time the wrapper should provide a good interface so that the developer's do not shoot their feet. So I came on the internet to get more ideas. But eventually the code has to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

We are getting near the end of a long project to wrap and remove RW in legacy code. I will use RWOrdered as an example, replacing it with OOrdered.

If you have code with RW in it, it is probably legacy code. If you find removing RW not to be trivial, it is probably large. You probably no longer understand all the details of its design. Changing how it works may cause a lot of trouble. Any interface or behavior differences between RWOrdered and OOrdered are to be avoided.

If you replace RW with something just like RW, you get rid of license fees, own all of your code, can do 64 bit builds, etc. But you don't get anything better than RW. You probably don't want to use it as the basis of all future containers.

RW was world class code in its day. You are replacing it with home built software, even if you wrap world class std containers. Sometimes std classes work differently than RW classes. You will have to solve problems that have been solved by RW. You will also find the std library solves problems RW did not.

- C++ templated containers are strongly typed. RW containers can contain anything that inherits from RWCollectable. That is, you can mix types. Making OOrdered a template class may not be what you want.
- std classes make a clear distinction between equivalence and equality. The find() algorithm uses equality, operator==(), to find an item. set<> is sorted, usually by operator<(). When set::insert(a) uses equivalence based on this operator to determine if an item is already in the set. It looks for an item b where a < b and b < a are both false.

In RW, RWCollectable defines isEqual(), compareTo(), and hash(). That is, equivalence and equality are available to all collections. Sometimes, RW mixes equality and equivalence, particularly when collections are nested.

You need to be aware of which RW function does what, as well as which std library entity does what. You need to choose to exactly match RW behavior, or how you want to differ.

- These examples are easily solved, but some are harder. Serialization was a pain point for us. We wanted to use boost serialization to replace SaveGuts() and RestoreGuts(). We have nested containers, where sometime an inner container is allocated by a different DLL than the outer container. This breaks boost. Work arounds exist, but they are not trivial.

---

Take it in steps.

- Write OCollectable, which wraps RWCollectable.
- Write a type that inherits from OCollectable, such as OWidget. RW defines macros that implement some base functionality like isA(). Use the macros.
- Write OOrdered, which wraps RWOrdered.
- Replace RWOrderd and Widget in your code. If they behave exactly the same, your code will still work.
- Expand the macros
- Add a std::vector to OOrdered. Rewrite OOrdered member functions. Drop ones you don't use.
- Rewrite Widget functions.
- One way to expose the wrapped vector is to add a getVector() function. A typedef for the return type will help.
- Another way is to add functions expose the vector functions you want.
- Test, test, test

---

Gotchas

- Getting rid of some RW is not too hard. Getting rid of every last trace is harder. For example, your OWidget inherits from OCollectable, which inherits from RWCollectable. So you can take a widget out of your OOrdered, and hand it to a method that takes an RWCollectable. If you change OCollectable so that it no longer inherits, you can't pass your OWidget class in any more. You have to wait until the end of your project to drop RWCollectable, when everything inherits from OCollectable.
- By the time you are done, you will be an expert in a dead library in a dying language. This may be better for your career than it sounds. People who don't want to dig into it themselves need such experts. On the other hand, you will also know a lot about some proprietary legacy code. You might prefer a career in steam engines.
- Likewise, you will be familiar with std library. Effective STL is dated, but still a really good book. There isn't any equivalent for RW. This is good. It keeps the market from being flooded with RW experts.